# Conditional Identity/autoincrement in a SQL Table

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlalchemy

I currently have two tables in a SQL-Database (we plan to use MS SQL Server but we try to keep it agnostic via `sqlalchemy`).

We have one table acting like an index:

[image: index table]

Where the column DefinitionID is defined in SQLAlchemy as

```
Column("DefinitionID", Integer, Identity(start=1, increment=1), primary_key=True,
                      autoincrement=True)
```

Then a second table with two columns: One ValueID with is defined similar to the one above:

```
Column("ValueID", Integer, Identity(start=1, increment=1), primary_key=True,
                      autoincrement=True)
```

and the second one that refers to the value in the first table:

```
Column("DefinitionID", Integer, ForeignKey("Table1.DefinitionID"))
```

If I upload 6 elements, 3 referring to `DefinitionID=1` and 3 to `DefinitionID=2`, I get something like
:

[image: Current result]

What I would like to achieve is to have the database to assigned the value of `ValueID` in an incremental fashion, based on the value on the `DefinitionID`, i.e., something like

[image: Desired result]

Of course I could do a lookup, see what is the highest value currently provided and increased by one, but I wonder if there is a way to let the database do that for me in a safe way.

Comment: Identity columns are surrogate keys.  Their sole purpose is to be unique in the table. Anything else is incorrect and flawed use.  The fix isn't to change how the ValueID's are being generated, the fix is to change how you're using/querying them. 
 Please can you show cases where you believe you are unable to use the ValueID's you're currently (correctly) generating?  I'm sure we can show you ways of achieving what you want without needing/trying to abuse an identity column.

Comment: What I am afraid of is to run out of `ValueID` too early (being restriced to `Integer` as type, hence 2^32-1 values). Being, in my logic, the duple `(ValueID,DefinitionID)` effectively unique, it seems a waste to me. But if have to choose, I would keep automatic numbering.

Comment: There are two billion positive INT values, that takes quite some time to overflow. The are 8 quintillion positive BIGINT values, that is never realistically going to overflow (1 a second for 292 billion years...)

Comment: you are probably right.